# What are these text formatting marks and how can I intentionally insert them in another file?

Tags: text-formatting

I'm trying to solve a problem that involves reading and parsing special data files.

In my IDE ( Slickedit ) the data file has unknown text formatting characters represented as blank rectangles:

[image]

I fired up EMACS and saw that these characters are represented there as ^M,^A,^C :

[image]

What are these characters?

I have to reconstruct such a data file, so how can I intentionally insert them into a new file once I know what they are?

Comment: You'll do better looking at the file in a hex editor than in EMACS.

Comment: Can you recommend one?  Will I be able to type normal text in it as well?

Comment: You can Google *hex editor unix* (or whatever OS you're using). You can edit and type into the file, but it's primarily used to edit the hex content of files, not plain text. The hex editor will show you the actual values of those characters in hex, which will let you look them up in an ASCII table (which you can also find easily using Google).

Comment: I looked in my package manager, there are at least a dozen, that is why I asked for a recommendation.

Comment: You're only using it to examine this file (not modify it), so it really doesn't matter. You should probably be made aware that (other than `^M`, which is a carriage return), the characters you're asking about are not found in normal text files, which means that the file is in some sort of proprietary format - editing it or creating your own may not work without knowing the specifications of that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When emacs prints a character as `^X` like this, it means it is a control character -- the ascii character with the value 0x40 less than the corresponding upper-case character.

So ^A is '\x01' -- SOH, ^M is '\x0d' -- CR, and ^^ is '\x1e' -- RS